# How to exclude manytomany object in query?

Tags: django, django-models

I created my own manager:

```
class DataManager(models.Manager):

    def optfilter(self, options = dict()):

    kwargs = dict()
    if options.has_key('active'):
        kwargs['active__id'] = options['active']

    return self.filter(**kwargs)
```

active is ManyToMany field.

and it working exacly as I want. But what about when I want exclude object from filter?
Something like this:

```
kwargs['exclude_active_id'] = options['active']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same idea as you're already implemented except use exclude instead of filter

Comment: I can't. I must realize this in my filter because it is strongly universal object.

Comment: Uhh, you're right. exclude['active__id'] = options['active'] and return self.filter(**kwargs).exclude(**exclude) work. Thanks!